# html array passed to python script via php

Tags: php, python, html, arrays

I try to pass data from a html input in an array via php section to a python script. This script is executed on button click and just writes its argument into a txt-file.

html section:

```
<input type="number" id="Uhrzeit_mo" name="day[]" value="" Maxlength="5" size="4">
<a href="?id=schedule" target="_parent"><button>Senden</button></a>
```

php section:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    if($id == "button_on") {
        shell_exec("sudo /var/www/gpiotest2.py 3");
    } elseif($id == "schedule") {
        $day = $_POST['day'][0];
        $day2 = 6;
        shell_exec("sudo /var/www/params.py {$day} {$day2}");
    }
}
?>
```

First conditional statement works fine if executed. second doesn't. $day won't be written into the text file and I dunno why.

additional question for better debugging: is there a way to redirect error messages because my putty terminal stays empty when the script is triggered via the button click. btw the scipt itself works fine.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an array from html via php as argument to python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875345/passing-an-array-from-html-via-php-as-argument-to-python-script)

Comment: Tell us - what's the difference?

Comment: Nowhere in this code are you trying to write anything into a text file.

Comment: it is done in the python script `shell_exec("sudo /var/www/params.py {$day} {$day2}");` if I execute that exact python script on the shell terminal via `python /var/www/params.py arg1 arg2` it works fine. It even works fine if I replace `$day = $_POST['day'][0];`by e.g. `$day = 5;`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quotation mark near MaxLength in this line:
`<input type="time" id="Uhrzeit_mo" name="day[]" value="10:00" Maxlength=5" size="4">`

That will definitely change what is being passed in the variable.

As for in the PHP. In the second conditional, add an 'else' statement with an alert box posting what the value of you variable is. It seem's you are not getting the value that you think you are getting.

Comment: thank you, I am sorry I copied the wrong line `<input type="number" id="Uhrzeit_mo" name="day[]" value="" Maxlength="5" size="4">` and putting in e.g. 2 does not work either.